# remoteFunction not working in Grails

Tags: ajax, grails, html-select

I have two drop down select tags(g:select), and I want to create ajax logic. when I choose some value from first select, the second select must be update, but something is wrong and nothin is coming to the second one. this is my code:

**controller:**

```
def getModels(params) {
    def models = Models.findAll {
        car.name == params.name
    }
    println (models.modelName)
    return [models:models]
}
```

**view:**

```
<div>
    <label class="label_title">Select Maker:</label>
    <g:select class="select_styled" name="car_maker" from="${cars.name}"
    keys="${cars.name}"
    onchange="${remoteFunction(
        controller:'home',
        action:'getModels',
        update: [success:'car_models'],
        params: '\'name=\' + this.value')}" />
</div>

<div class="row field_select" >
    <label class="label_title">Select Model:</label>
    <g:select class="select_styled" name="car_model" id="car_models"
        from="${models}" />
</div>
```

what is the problem?

EDIT:

println (models.modelName) print the right values in console, so, the method call is working, but the problem in returning the models to the view. it returns null

thanks!

Comment: Try `render(models.collect{"<option>${it.modelName}</option>"}.join(''))`

Comment: I get this error "Cannot get property 'modelName' on null object". but the models is not null

Comment: models is a list, so it should not have modelName.  I think the id="car_models" shoul dbe in the div not in g:select

Comment: @JavaDev the problem the getModels action return NULL object to the view, but println show values in console, I cant send models:models to the view or another action, it sends null and I can't understand why

Comment: Can you share your full controller?

Comment: I find the way for this job. i used template and render the template, but now I have design problems, after the template render after ajax call, the design of css crashed. in firebug I noticed, that the second's select name is initialized as id tag. e.x if the g:select class="blah" name="second_blah", then in firebug after ajax call i see the #second_blah.blah css style tag, thats why the design crashes and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: are you open to rewrite this? i can provide a sample